# Sound volume settings don't persist through reboots

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

By default, my speakers come up with 25% of volume:

```
~ $ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Capabilities: volume
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: 0 - 255
Front Left: 64 [25%]
Front Right: 64 [25%]
```

I also check the `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` and sure enough, it's set at 25%.

So i set it to be 75% and volume goes up fine:

```
sudo amixer set Master 75%
```

I now store the settings:

```
sudo alsactl store
```

To be sure, I double checked the `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` file and it's at 75%.  So I reboot.

Once I reboot, I check the `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` file and it's back to 25%.  What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

P.S.  I am on the Raspberry Pi Zero 2W with Raspbian v10 (Buster).  And the sound card being used is the one attached to the HDMI port.

Comment: Any chance that you run good old openrc ? In which case the solution is in /etc/conf.d/alsasound (RESTORE_ON_START="yes"  and SAVE_ON_STOP="yes") and alsasound started as a service at boot.

Comment: @MC68020 There is not file `/etc/conf.d/alsasound` that I can tell.  There isn't a `conf.d` directory in `etc` either.